# Не получается восстановить backup в MS SQL в докер контейнере

Tags: sql, sql-server, docker-compose

Не получается восстановить БД в доккер контейнере с помощью скрипта:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DBName]
FROM
    DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/DBName.bak'
```

При попытке восстановить его, выдает следующие ошибки:

1. Directory lookup for the file
   "C:\DATA\MSSQL15\MSSQL\DATA\DBName.mdf" failed with the
   operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file
   specified.).
2. File 'DBName' cannot be restored to
   'C:\DATA\MSSQL15\MSSQL\DATA\DBName.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to
   identify a valid location for the file.
3. Directory lookup for the file
   "C:\DATA\MSSQL15\MSSQL\DATA\DBName_log.ldf" failed with
   the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file
   specified.).
4. File 'DBName_log' cannot be restored to
   'C:\DATA\MSSQL15\MSSQL\DATA\DBName.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to
   identify a valid location for the file.
5. Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement.
   Previous messages provide details.
6. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Через интерфейс восстановить БД не получается, проблема аналогичная, также пытался получить LogicalName PhysicalName:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
    FROM DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/DBName.bak'
```

и восстановить след образом:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DBName]
    FROM
        DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/DBName.bak'
    WITH  FILE = 1, 
    MOVE N'DBName' TO N'C:\DATA\MSSQL15\MSSQL\DATA\DBName.mdf',
    MOVE N'DBName_log' TO N'C:\DATA\MSSQL15\MSSQL\DATA\DBName.ldf',
    NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
```

Тем не менее не получается, посоветуйте, как восстановить БД через скрипт?

Comment: Через интерфейс есть кнопка получить скрипт. Возьмите его за основу.

Comment: Я ошибся, через интерфейс аналогичная проблема. Хотя раньше работало, но теперь даже через интерфейс не получается восстановить бэкап. Ошибки аналогичные